# Datatable no muestra registros en laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatables

tengo una vista en la cual tengo un datatable que me tiene que cargar los registros asociados a cierto usuario (segun el id del usuario logueado) pero resulta que carga la vista, carga el datatable y no trae el/los registros, no da error en consola ni alertas de error...

En mi controlador tengo asi la funcion:

```
public function dtMantencionesUsuario(Request $request, $idusuario){
$mantenimientos = DB::table('mantenimientos as m')
->join('mantenimiento_ejecutors as me' , 'me.mantenimiento_id' , 'm.id')
->join('clientes as c' , 'c.id' , 'm.cliente_id')
->join('cliente_sedes as cs' , 'cs.cliente_id' ,'c.id')
->join('tableros as t' , 't.id' , 'm.tablero_id')
->join('users as u' , 'u.id' ,'me.user_id')
->select('m.id', 'm.fecha_mantenimiento', 'm.status',
 'c.razon_social', 'cs.sede_nombre', 't.tablero_nombre', 'u.name', 'u.ape_pat')
->where('me.user_id', $idusuario)
->get();

return $mantenimientos;

//dd($personal);
return datatables()->of($mantenimientos)

->addColumn('action', function($row){
     return '<a href="/sistema/admin/mantenimientos/'.$row->id.'" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Ver</a> <a href="/sistema/mantenimiento/ejecutar/'.$row->id.'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Registrar</a> ';


    })
    ->rawColumns(['action'])
    ->make(true);
```

}

y en la vista el script lo tengo asi:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var idusuario = $("#id_user").val();

    console.log(idusuario);
     //DataTable
    var table = $('#mantenimientos').DataTable({


          url:"{{ route('data.mantenciones.usuario', 'idusuario')  }}" ,
          /* url:"{{ url('sistema/data/mantenciones/usuario') }}"  + '/' + idusuario, */
          columns: [
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'fecha_mantenimiento', name: 'fecha_mantenimiento'},
                {"data":"nombres",
                render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                    // esto es lo que se va a renderizar como html
                    return `${row.name} ${row.ape_pat} ${row.ape_mat}`;
                    }
                },


              {data: 'razon_social', name: 'razon_social'},
              {data: 'sede_nombre', name: 'sede_nombre'},
              {data: 'tablero_nombre', name: 'tablero_nombre'},
              {data: 'status' , render: function (data, type, row) { return data == 0 ?  '<h6><span class="badge badge-success">PENDIENTE</span></h6>' : '<h6><span class="badge badge-danger">INACTIVO</span></h6>' ; }},

              {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
            ],
            "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",
            "zeroRecords": "No hay Registros por mostrar",
            "info": "Mostrando pagina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "No records available",
            "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ registros totales)",
            "search": "Buscar:",
            "paginate":{
            "next": "Siguiente",
            "previous" : "Anterior"
            },
         }
    });

</script>
```

En consola imprimo la variable y me muestra correctamente el id del usuario que esta logueado, la consulta si la pruebo tambien me trae la data:

```
[{"id":2,"fecha_mantenimiento":"2022-09-05","status":0,"razon_social":"prueba Spa","sede_nombre":"Casa Matriz","tablero_nombre":"009-87","name":"Robert","ape_pat":"Pereira"}]
```

La ruta la tengo asi:

```
Route::get('sistema/data/mantenciones/usuario/{id}', [MantenimientoController::class, 'dtMantencionesUsuario'])->name('data.mantenciones.usuario');
```

No se que puede estar fallando la verdad que le he dado muchas vueltas y no se que sucede....

Saludos a todos

Answer (score 0):

RESUELTO: por si a alguien mas le llega a pasar, me di cuenta que me faltaba incluir la llamada ajax en el script del datatable...finalmente me quedo asi:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });


    var idusuario = $("#id_user").val();

    var table = $('#mantenimientos').DataTable({
        /* url:"sistema/data/mantenciones/usuario/3" , */
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            type:'GET',
            url:"sistema/data/mantenciones/usuario/"+idusuario ,
            data: {
            "user": idusuario
            },
        },
          columns: [
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'fecha_mantenimiento', name: 'fecha_mantenimiento'},
                {"data":"nombres",
                render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                    // esto es lo que se va a renderizar como html
                    return `${row.name} ${row.ape_pat}`;
                    }
                },


              {data: 'razon_social', name: 'razon_social'},
              {data: 'sede_nombre', name: 'sede_nombre'},
              {data: 'tablero_nombre', name: 'tablero_nombre'},
              {data: 'status' , render: function (data, type, row) { return data == 0 ?  '<h6><span class="badge badge-success">PENDIENTE</span></h6>' : '<h6><span class="badge badge-danger">INACTIVO</span></h6>' ; }},

              {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
            ],
            "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",
            "zeroRecords": "No hay Registros por mostrar",
            "info": "Mostrando pagina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "No records available",
            "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ registros totales)",
            "search": "Buscar:",
            "paginate":{
            "next": "Siguiente",
            "previous" : "Anterior"
            },
         }
    });

</script>
```